# Androidn Studio Hierarchy Viewer not working with emulator

Tags: android

I'm trying to use the Hierarchy viewer to see a screen shot of my app in pixel perfect view. I'm using an emulator and whenever I try to inspect the screen shot I get the errors:

```
 -Unable to get view server version from device emulator
 -Unable to get view server protocol version from device emulator
 -Timeout loading screenshot from device
```

What could be a possible fix? I've already tried restarting ADB server.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this:
adb kill-server
adb start-server

Comment: why you think this solution would work? did you tried it? did it worked? And can you update your answer explaining why it worked!